# Printing source code from sql server 2005 stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 40 or so stored procedures that i would like to be able to print out and refactor on paper then make the changes to the procedures. I have come across a couple of different possibilities but none so far that fit what I want but a little tweaking may fix that. the first

```
select 
  text 
from 
  syscomments 
where 
  id in (select id from sysobjects where xtype='p' and name LIKE 'qscore_Corp%')
```

but this returns all the code unformatted on single lines.

using sp_helptext is an option also but i have not figured out how to concatenate multiple into one long table of text.

My goal is to make it so that I can print the source of these 40 procedures from one text file with the formatting i have used in each procedure.

SOLVED::: By Martin thanks again. 
I made a small tweak to his solution that pulled the procs i needed. 
        DECLARE @stored_procedure_code nvarchar(MAX) 
        SET @stored_procedure_code = ''

```
    SELECT @stored_procedure_code = @stored_procedure_code + '' + ISNULL(OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id),'')
    FROM sys.procedures WHERE name LIKE 'qscore_Corp%'

    SELECT  @stored_procedure_code AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: I can't recall all the menu's etc, and don't have a Management Studio here, but...  If you script the objects in a database, you can choose to script all the Stored Procedures, with or without the preceding DROP statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something Like

```
DECLARE @stored_procedure_code nvarchar(MAX) = ''

SELECT @stored_procedure_code = @stored_procedure_code + '
/*****************************************************************************/
GO

' + ISNULL(OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id),'')
FROM sys.procedures 
WHERE object_id IN (object_id('foo'),object_id('foo_bar'))

SELECT  @stored_procedure_code AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: Amazing solution i will post in my original the code that i ended up using only as a reference to the tweak i made but thank you so much martin for your idea.

Comment: @MichaelCole - I'm guessing you're going to say `name LIKE 'usp_foo%'`? The only reason I used `object_id` was in case you had the same object name in different schemas - tbh I hadn't noticed you were using `LIKE` in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT definition
    FROM sys.sql_modules m
        INNER JOIN sys.objects o
            ON m.object_id = o.object_id
    WHERE o.type = 'P'
        AND o.name LIKE 'qscore_Corp%'
```

Comment: a good solution that results in the same result set as my original query (the first one not the solved one) only problem with this is i was trying to print it out so that i could make changes on paper then go back to the database and make the changes and with this solution there is no formatting.